# What does this sentence mean? From a Film Review of Bohemian Rhapsody 2

Tags: meaning

In a movie review from Time (http://time.com/5440357/bohemian-rhapsody-freddie-mercury-queerness/ ), there are a few sentences I don’t understand.

> What made Freddie Mercury such a captivating public figure is the same
>   thing that makes him such a difficult subject to capture fully on
>   film: his multitudes. Examine his sexuality alone and **you have
>   contractions twisting and knotting within one rather petite man**. He
>   never formally came out, yet his queerness was imprinted on the very
>   band he fronted and named, Queen. He is said to have had an insatiable
>   appetite for sex with men, yet his most enduring relationship seems to
>   have been with a woman to whom he was once engaged (and who inherited
>   the majority of his fortune when he died of AIDS in 1991), Mary
>   Austen. He fluidly presented along the femme-butch spectrum, equally
>   convincing in glam drag, in drag drag, and in the cartoonishly
>   masculine “Castro clone” uniform (tight jeans, tank top, an imposing
>   mustache, muscles) that originated in San Francisco in the early ’70s.

Please have a look at the emboldened sentence. I don’t understand what “contractions” means here. I looked up in a dictionary but I don’t feel the given definitions make sense. Is “twisting and knotting” an idiom? But I have no idea at all.

Comment: Probably a typo for "contradictions"?  The review goes on to list a series of contradictions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a typo. **The word should be "contradictions".** The "A yet B" structure of the subsequent sentences makes that clear.